# How to input a value and calculate the exchange rate of the currency on other input tag onkeyup and onchange

Tags: javascript

I am creating a currency exchange website portal. However, I can't get my code to work properly. When I input a value (onkeyup and onchange), I need to calculate the exchange rate of the currency. All I get is a blank input or `NaN`.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="box">
<h2>Currency Converter </h2>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="fromAmount" type="text" size="15" value="1" onkeyup="convertCurrency();">
</td>
<td>
<select id="from" onchange="convertCurrency();">
<option value="ETH">ETHEREUM</option>
<option value="LTC">LITECOIN</option>
<option value="BCH">BITCOIN CASH</option>
<option value="BTC" selected>BITCOIN</option>
<option value="DASH">DASH</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<input id="toAmount" type="text" size="15" value="" oninput="convertCurrency();">
</td>
<td>
<select id="to" onchange="convertCurrency();">
<option value="ETH" selected>ETHEREUM</option>
<option value="LTC">LITECOIN</option>
<option value="BCH">BITCOIN CASH</option>
<option value="BTC">BITCOIN</option>
<option value="DASH">DASH</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

And here is my javascript

```
function convertCurrency() {

  var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
  var to = document.getElementById("to").value;

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref=" + to + "&symbol=" + from;
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

      var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
      var jsResult = JSON.parse(result);
      var oneUnit = jsResult.price[from] / jsResult.price[to];
      var amt = document.getElementById("fromAmount").value;
      document.getElementById("toAmount").value = (oneUnit * amt).toFixed(2);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is trying to do. `from` is already the value of the input, but then later you're checking if `from.value` is NaN. In fact, `from.value` is undefined because `from` is already just a string, the value of the input. What is that actually meant to be checking?

Comment: i was trying to remove the NaN but then the code isnt giving me a value in the input tag of the html code

Comment: please help me figure this out

Comment: If you `console.log` the value of `jsResult`, is it in the format you expect? I just went to the URL you're using, and the result seems to be a different format than how you're trying to access the prices...

Comment: so please how best can i achieve a better result

Comment: Look at the actual format of the JSON that the API returns, and access it correctly? Try to make the changes and then update the post with your new code if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: i have done that but price is what i see that i need to use in the JSON API data

Comment: {
    "symbol": "ETH",
    "show_symbol": "ETH",
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "rank": 2,
    "price": "0.018833884",
    "market_cap": "2058361.0067864701",
    "total_volume_24h": "464898.2037110419",
    "low_24h": "0.0187028363",
    "high_24h": "0.0193387502",
    "delta_1h": "0.49",
    "delta_24h": "0.82",
    "delta_7d": "9.41",
    "delta_30d": "-4.71"

Comment: The value of `price` is a string containing a number. So if it's just a string, then what are you trying to access with `jsResult.price[from]` and `jsResult.price[to]`?

Comment: please can u help me with an improved code, i seem not to get it

Comment: i did this yet not working   var price= xmlhttp.responseText;
//alert(price);
var jsprice = JSON.parse(price);
var oneUnit = jsprice.price[fromAmount]/jsprice.price[toAmount];
var amt = document.getElementById("fromAmount").value;
document.getElementById("toAmount").value = (oneUnit * amt).toFixed(2);

Comment: please can anyone help me with this code

Comment: @ IceMetalPunk i cant still get it to work, please help me modify my code. its really killing me here

Comment: Please can anyone help me in resolving the issue with my javascript code.